# Active Directory Validation is Slow in PHP

Tags: php, performance, active-directory, ldap

So I'm validating username, password, and group membership in active directory like so:

```
function validate($username, $password, $groupname = null) {
  if ($username && $password) {
    $link = ldap_connect($domain);
    if ($link) {
      ldap_set_option($link, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
      $bind = ldap_bind($link, $username, $password);
      if ($bind) {
        if ($groupname) {
          $filter  = "(samAccountName=".$username.")";
          $attrs   = array("memberOf");
          $res     = ldap_search($link, $baseDN, $filter, $attrs);
          $entries = ldap_get_entries($link, $res);
          $isMember = false;
          if ($entries && $entries[0] && $entries[0]['memberof']) {
            $arr = $entries[0]['memberof'];
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
              if ($key != 'count') {
                $isMember = $isMember || preg_match("|".preg_quote($groupname)."|", $value);
              }
            }
          }
          return $isMember;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      error_log("Could not connect to Active Directory");
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    error_log("Username or password missing");
    return false;
  }
}
```

This works correctly, but is *painfully* slow, taking as much as 2~3 minutes to validate that a user is a member of a group.. If I omit the group membership check it runs almost instantaneously. How can I speed this up (without caching)?

## EDIT

since it was not clear from the question, the bottle neck is the `ldap_search` function which takes ~127 seconds, rest of the program runs in less than a second. Should also add that we only have about 20 AD users and 10ish groups.

Comment: Does it take that long when you pass an empty ```$attrs``` to ```ldap_search```?

Comment: Result was identical.

Comment: What is your base-DN? Am I right that the LDAP has a rather LARGE and distributed directory-tree?

Comment: this sounds weird. As with 20 users it should be fast as nothing. Can you reproduce that timing with a commandline-tool like ```ldapsearch -h ldap -b=baseDN "samAccountName=username" memberof````? You might want to contact me via https://gitter.im/heiglandreas or IRC on Freenode (heiglandreas)

Comment: Yeah I thought it was weird. I'm validating against the exact same AD with node.js in less than a second, but this app has to use PHP per the requirements. I sent you a gitter msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ar first it looked to me like the `foreach`-loop with a `preg_match` inside takes some time. Especially if there are a lot of groups to check.

But then it became clear that there were only 10 groups and about 20 users in the AD, so it had to be something different.

In the end it was an issue with missing timeouts. Adding  `ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10);` right before the `ldap_search()` cured the issue.

It looks as if in that special case a connection to the LDAP-Server has been opened but the LDAP-Server didn't respond correctly and therefore the client was waiting for an answer until the timeout was hit. Setting this timeout to a much smaller value than the default (which is indefinite) caused the ldap_search to return much earlier as it needs no longer to wait.

AFAIK this has been fixed in PHP-5.6.14 and PHP-7.0.0

Comment: No, the PHP code might be slower than yours, but still runs almost instantaneously. Simply using `preg_match` instead of `strpos` does not make the runtime blow up by ten orders of magnitude. The problem lies somewhere in the fetching the results from AD. I just didn't know if there was a better pattern to accomplish this than `ldap_search`/`ldap_get_entries`.

Comment: So where's the bottleneck? How long does the ```ldap_search``` and the ```ldap_get_entries``` take? And does it make a difference whether you set ```$attrs = ['memberof']``` or ```$attrs = []```?

Comment: Updated answer according to the result of our chat